# How can I fscanf a maximum of three integers on a line?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working in c on windows.

Here's the problem I'm struggling with since 2 hours :

I have a file as input, and I know that there will be numbers on the first line.

I also know that there will be no whitespaces on this line.

However, I don't know how these numbers will be separated, and I'd like to only get the first 3 integers found (there may be less than 3 integers, in that case, they should take 0 as value).

I would prefer a way without regex.h, only using fscanf filters, but I will rely on any good solution.

In a nutshell :

What I know :

- The line will have at least 1 integer
- Integers will be separated by some chars
- There are no whitespace on that line

What I don't know :

- The number of integers
- The length of integers
- The separators (type & length)

What I'd like :

- Place the first 3 integers encountered in vars (int)

If need arises, I can make sure the delimiters are all the same, and of length 1.

Comment: Ah, I just read about the unknown separaters. In that case, use `strtok`. Or if they can be *any* non-digit character, traverse the string yourself, looking for where each number begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this. I used `sscanf` instead of `fscanf` and did not fully implement all the requirements, but you can adapt the idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void parse(char *str)
{
    printf("String = %s\n", str);
    int a, b, c;
    int items = sscanf(str, " %*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d items converted\n", items);
    if(items >= 1)
        printf("Item 1 = %d\n", a);
    if(items >= 2)
        printf("Item 2 = %d\n", b);
    if(items >= 3)
        printf("Item 3 = %d\n", c);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    parse("abc!&123");
    parse("ywtas123-&=456xyz");
    parse("*':^123v456?987");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
String = abc!&123
1 items converted
Item 1 = 123

String = ywtas123-&=456xyz
2 items converted
Item 1 = 123
Item 2 = 456

String = *':^123v456?987
3 items converted
Item 1 = 123
Item 2 = 456
Item 3 = 987
```

Comment: All right, I thank you a lot, I guess it's approximatively what I did ?

Comment: You posted first, actually, but as commented you don't take account of how many numeric values were found.

Comment: I preset the values before and I just added a check after the scan, I wonder if it is enough ?

Comment: Perhaps, but please get into the habit of checking the return value from the `scanf` function family every time you use it.

Comment: Ok, then I'll do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the specifier `%*[^-0-9]` to match and discard any character that isn't `-` or a digit.

```
int a, b, c;
fscanf(f, "%d%*[^-0-9]%d%*[^-0-9]%d%*[^\n]", &a, &b, &c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, I finally went with @Weather-vane solution (his first one) and @isrnick too :

```
fscanf(input_file, "%s", BUFFER);
printf("test : %s\n", BUFFER); // Just to check
sscanf(BUFFER, "%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &var_num, &var_prec, &mode);
```

It clears all problems due to trailing new lines.
It avoids loops as well, and for now, I do not have any bug.

Comment: you may want to add something like `int n = sscanf(...); if (n == 3) /* can use mode, var_prec, and var_num */; else if (n == 2) /* can use var_prec and var_num */; else if (n == 1) /* can use only var_num */; else /* can't use nothing */;`

Comment: You think so ? it works just fine the way I use it, but is there any risk ?

Comment: Note that since `-` is being discarded (it wasn't included in the exclusion list) your sscanf will only match integers equal or greater than zero.

Comment: How do you distinguish between input `"foo42bar100"` and input `"foo42quux"`?

Comment: well, for "foo42bar100", I get 42, 100 and my default 0.
For "foo42quux", I get 42, default 256 and default 0. @pmg

Comment: ok then, if you take care to do the correct assignments before scanf.

Comment: Well I can give you the green mark if you want it, I just marked my answer as accepted because it's actually what I've been using since then, without problems, and I just wanted a reminder for myself or others that this particular solution works just fine.